# if this href contains a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to check if href contains a var. No luck so far

```
  var navcur = window.location.href;
  $(".subnavli").each(function(){
    if ($(this).find("a[href=" + navcur + "]")) {alert('works!');}  
  });
```

Comment: You should check the `length` of the collection.

Comment: Suggest use ``console.log("something");`` to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the href have special chars you need to wrap the attribute value. Also .find() returns a jQuery object irrespective of whether a match is found or not so you need to check whether the jQuery object contains any elements - you can check the length property for that

```
var navcur = window.location.href;
$(".subnavli").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("a[href='" + navcur + "']").length) {
        alert('works!');
    }
});
```

---

It can be simplified using descendant selector instead of using a loop

```
var navcur = window.location.href;
var $a = $(".subnavli a[href='" + navcur + "']");
if ($a.length) {
    alert('works!');
}
```

Comment: alright! this works! i'll accept answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
 var navcur = window.location.href

 $(".subnavli").each(function(){      
   if ($(this).attr("href") ===navcur) {alert('works!');}  
 });
```